# Ideas for the following function?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I would like to develop a function which would always based on the first element in the list extract further elements of the nested list.
Example:
Input:

```
lst= [[1,2,3],[3,4,5,6,8,9], [0,3,4], [1,4,5,6], [4,9,8,6,5,2]]
```

The first element in the sublist always determines the number of following elements to append to a new list.
Output:

```
Out=[2,4,5,6,4,9,8,6,5]
```

Elements are always an integer values.

Comment: See the simple`-loop` to get output.  Or try `List Comprehension`.

Comment: Welcome to SO @david_jopo! In the future pleas include the language, and show the work that you tried already

Comment: As @camelBack already mentioned, welcome to SO! It would be appropriate if you edit the title of your post in form of a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you expect:

Or you can convert this to List Comprehension later.

```
out = []

for sub in lst:                 # loop each sublist
    start = sub[0]              # use the first num. to determine
    out.extend(sub[1: 1+start]) # get each sublist by slicing
```

print(out)

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 9, 8, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Sharp code! @DanielHao